# How many gigs does it take to spotlight index 550 gigs?

Tags: macos, spotlight, disk-space

I had 450 gigs of free space on my laptop out of a total of 1000 when I asked the spotlight index to compile.  After it was done I only had 218 gigs.  Seems like a lot to me.  Is this normal?

I have a Macbook Pro 15 inch 2018.  Operating system is 13.6.3 Ventura.  I started the index I think 3 days ago.

[image: time machine settings]

Comment: Have you got Time Machine running? It could be snapshots, which you can check in Disk Utility - `View | Show / Hide APFS Snapshots`.

Comment: See above for update.  Also your terminal command does not work on my computer most likely because I used the old bash whereas ventura switched over to a new system whose name i've forgotten

Comment: It's not a terminal command (and you're thinking of `zsh` btw), it's the menu options in the Disk Utility app. TM will accumulate snapshots on the source disk if enabled, even if the backup disk is not connected. The extra churn caused by Spotlight indexing can cause extra snapshot space being used. The included picture isn't really necessary.

Answer (score 1):

It takes several days for the spotlight index to compile.  In my case it was four or five days.  Around day 2 it dropped to 220 gigs, but then magically it went back up to where it was before the index compiled.  So I suppose during the indexing process, the computer uses up a lot of the harddrive space.  Weird, but true.